# Calculate Variance from Dirichlet-like Distribution Empirically

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, dirichlet-distribution

I'm interested in the proportion of time that a sensor is in a particular state.  The sensor tells me the amount of time that it's in each state, which I will denote by $X = \{ X_1, X_2, X_3\}$.  I also set the interval time over which the sensor can be in any one of those states, which is a known duration that I will denote by $T$.
$$
T = \sum_{i = 1}^3 X_i
$$
I'm really interested in the proportion of the known interval time, $T$, that the sensor is in each state, $X$.
$$
p_i = \dfrac{X_i}{T}
$$
I am measuring $X$ and know $T$. The sensor also outputs the $\text{sd}(X_1)$ and the $\text{sd}(X_2)$, but not the $\text{sd}(X_3)$.  I need to figure out how to calculate the $\text{sd}(X_3)$??? Here $\text{sd}(\cdot)$ refers to the standard deviation (which in this case is in units of time).  This is kind of like a Dirichlet distribution (thx to the clarification from @jbowman).  Any advice on how to treat this situation?  I basically need to calculate $X_1 + X_3$ (which is simple b/c I know both of these values) and the $\mathrm{Var}\left(X_1 + X_3 \right) \stackrel{?}{=} \mathrm{Var}(X_1) + \mathrm{Var}(X_3)$ (which is a little more difficult b/c I know one of the values, I just need to calculate the other given the constraints and make an assumption that the sum of the variances is the variances of the sum).

Comment: This is not a multinomial distribution, which is discrete and on the integers.  It most resembles a Dirichlet distribution.  I don't see how, if you have the measurements of $X_1$ etc., there is a standard deviation involved; if $X_1 = 4, X_2 = 6, T = 15$, where is there any variability in $X_1$?

Comment: @jbowman - the data from the sensor would be $X_1 = 4 \pm 1$ that might read 4 seconds plus / minus 1 second.  So perhaps I should of framed the $X$s as averages.  All the $X$s must sum to $T$, but there is some wiggle room there.  Does that clarify things?

Comment: Yes, mostly.  Is $T$ known with 100% accuracy, or does it have a std. deviation too?

Comment: @jbowman $T$ is known with 100% accuracy.

Comment: **You don't have enough information.**  The reason is that since $X_3=T-(X_1+X_2)$, the algebraic properties of variances imply $$\operatorname{sd}(X_3)^2=\operatorname{Var}(X_3)=\operatorname{Var}(T-X_1-X_2)=\operatorname{Var}(X_1+X_2)\\=\operatorname{Var}(X_1)+\operatorname{Var}(X_2)+\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\operatorname{sd}(X_1)^2+\operatorname{sd}(X_2)^2+\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2).$$ **You need information about this covariance** (or equivalently about the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$).

Comment: @whuber Thank you!  At one point I tried to use the equation for the variance of a Dirichlet distribution to work out an approximation, but came to the same conclusion that there were too many unknowns.  Your approach is way more eloquent, and much appreciated!